# Can't switch from detached HEAD when trying a hard reset?

Tags: git, version-control, git-reset

I made a test structure like so:

```
A - B - C
```

I checked out commit A, so I was in detached HEAD. But then I thought, "shouldn't a hard reset to the previous head do the same as checking out master?" So I tried it. I did

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

and it said `HEAD is now at 6bccb37 (commit C)`

But then when I ran `git status`, it said:

```
HEAD detached from d60bbb1 (commit A)
```

However, my working directory now matches commit C. Why is it still in detached HEAD state?

Comment: What your example illustrates is that a branch isn't the same as the commit it is currently pointing to. To see this in an even less convoluted way, assuming you have a branch called `master`, do `git checkout master` followed by `git checkout 6bccb37`. This will take your repo to a detached HEAD state. Any time HEAD isn't pointing to a branch, the repo is in detached HEAD.

Comment: @Pradhan ah that's exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you!